# Drag and sort divs using jQuery and output html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-snippets

**What i'm doing:**

I'm creating a Mailings Generator. This simply is an application, that generates Mailings (An E-mail with some of my products as advertisement) from a Mailing Template.

**What i want:**

I want to be able to order the divs generated in my Mailing Generator and create a new file with the new order.
Let me show you the concept:

```js
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.connectedSortable').each(function() {
            result = "";
            ($(this).sortable("toArray"));
            $(this).find("div").each(function(){
            result += $(this).text() + "<br />";
            });
            $("."+$(this).attr("id")+".list").html(result);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
<div id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
    
<div class="companyLogo">
<!--    logo here...-->
</div>

<div class="productBox1">
    Product Name: 1
    Price: 10,00
    <!--    etc...-->
</div>
<div class="productBox2">
    Product Name: 2
    Price: 20,00
    <!--    etc...-->
</div>
<div class="productBox3">
    Product Name: 3
    Price: 30,00
    <!--    etc...-->
</div>
<div class="productBox4">
    Product Name: 4
    Price: 40,00
    <!--    etc...-->
</div>

<div class="footerInformation">
<!--    Footer Info Here...-->
</div>
    
</div>

<div class="sortable list"></div>
```

So here's a quick example of how the mailing could look when generated. (Please run the code snippet)

I want to drag the divs and sort them the way i'd like.
After i sorted them i want to create a NEW file but this time display the divs in the order i sorted the last one.

**Question:**

When i move the div's, i get the new order as output. What i want is it to output all the html code. This way i want to create a new file with the new order.

If there is any way to do this and you know how, please consider helping me a little. Please correct me in any way possible. it helps me learn!

If i wasn't clear enough, please let me know.

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem on the clientside through the browser. However you could send the modified HTML back to the webserver (e.g. via ajax) then save it from severside.

Comment: @Mischa Could you be a little more specific? Send the modified HTML back to the webserver using ajax, how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you be a little more specific? Send the modified HTML back to the webserver using ajax, how would i do that?

You could for example add a Button. Then when u are done sorting your articles in the list you will click that button. The eventhandler attached to that button will then extract the html that you want to save to a file (`htmlToSend`) from the `$('#sortable')` element and send it to a certain server_address.

```js
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.connectedSortable').each(function() {
            result = "";
            $(this).sortable("toArray");
            $(this).find("div").each(function(){
              result += $(this).text() + "<br />";
            });
            $("."+$(this).attr("id")+".list").html(result);
        });
    }
});

$('#send').on('click', function() {
  const htmlToSend = $('#sortable').html();
  alert('SENDING HTML: ' + htmlToSend);
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '<SERVER_ADDRESS>', //CHANGE SERVER_ADDRESS to the address of the script that will handle the html (save it to file or send it via email)
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ html: htmlToSend }),
    success: function(response) {
      //code to execute if saving on server was successful
    },
    error: function(err){
      //code to execute if saving on server failed
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
  <div class="companyLogo">
  <!--    logo here...-->
  </div>

  <div class="productBox1">
      Product Name: 1
      Price: 10,00
      <!--    etc...-->
  </div>
  <div class="productBox2">
      Product Name: 2
      Price: 20,00
      <!--    etc...-->
  </div>
  <div class="productBox3">
      Product Name: 3
      Price: 30,00
      <!--    etc...-->
  </div>
  <div class="productBox4">
      Product Name: 4
      Price: 40,00
      <!--    etc...-->
  </div>

  <div class="footerInformation">
  <!--    Footer Info Here...-->
  </div>
    
</div>

<input type="button" value="Send to Server" id="send">
```

On the serverside you will need to receive that data from the post-body of the http-request. For example on a php-server u would use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to receive that. But that is dependant on your serverside technology that you use. So let me know if u have problems with the serverside implementation.